# "Gradle sync failed: Cannot assign requested address: Cannot bind" for Android Studio template project

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I opened Android Studio and chose new template project with "SettingsActivity" template and all default options.

Then I get error "Gradle sync failed: Cannot assign requested address: Cannot bind".

That's the only thing it says is wrong.

How to fix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue, and i found that my problem was due to my VPN, disconecting from VPN solved the issue, as the process tries to communicate with local IP & Socket, and of course if the flow is going outside by the VPN server, it can't find the local software server....

Hope it will help you

Kind regards

Stéphane

Comment: Yes, that solved it. Such an unhelpful error message...